# Firebase Dynamic link multiple redirects on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to use a Firebase dynamic link to open a webpage in the default web browser on Android. I want to use the dynamic link so that we can later update it to point at a different web page which is still under development.

The code is simple:

```
@OnClick(R.id.about_whats_new_row)
public void onWhatsNewClicked() {

    // start intent for web
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(WHATS_NEW_URL));
    this.startActivity(intent);

}
```

When the user clicks on the link, it first goes to a web browser, then it redirects back to my app (which cannot handle it, because I don't want to use deep linking for this content), then it redirects back to the web browser again.

[Gif of undesired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mvl3.gif)

Is there any way to cut down on these redirects?  I only want to open the link in the web browser directly.